# Puppet master fails to start

Tags: puppet

I have configured the puppet master and puppet agent in two docker containers and it was working fine.Now I cannot start the puppet master.

```
root@pmaster:/# service puppetmaster start
 * Starting puppet master                                               [fail] 
root@pmaster:/# sudo /etc/init.d/puppetmaster start
 * Starting puppet master                                               [fail] 
root@pmaster:/# service puppetmaster status
 * master is not running
```

Comment: "It worked before, now it doesn't." Woohoo, the most useful statement, ever. One can solve almost every problem with it. Unfortunately I'm not in the mood right now. Meanwhile you can look up some error logs or something.

Answer (score 0):

it might be to late now. But try to stop the puppetmaster as a service and start it in foreground.

```
puppet master --no-deaemonize
```

that might give you the required hint why it's not starting up.